# How to suppress warning QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread

Tags: python, qt, error-handling, pyqt, suppress-warnings

I am having this error flood my terminal and make it impossible to debug. Is there a way to silence this warning? This error only generated when I included a scrollToBottom() on my TableWidget.

Answer (score 9):

You **do not want to suppress that warning** because it's not a warning. It's an error. Qt is way too polite here. It should be a hard assertion, since the presence of it indicates that you wrote your code in such a way that it's likely to have corrupted the data of GUI objects and continuing past that point is a fool's errand.

Do not *ever* call GUI methods *directly* from other threads, unless those methods are explicitly documented to be thread safe.

If you need to make cross-thread calls, use indirect, thread-safe ways of doing so: `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` for slots and invokable methods on `QObject`s, or use a proxy `QObject`. If you're doing image updates from another thread, it's perfectly fine to pass `QImage` instances between threads using the signal-slot or metacall mechanism.

There's a really simple criterion to test: if a method of a `QObject`-derived class is *not* documented as thread-safe, you should be able to safely assert that the object is resident in the current thread:

```
Q_ASSERT(widget->thread() == QThread::currentThread());
widget->scrollToBottom();
```

It *doesn't matter* how "innocuous" the method seems to be. Could `TableWidget.scrollToBottom()` cause that much trouble? Yes. Or it could not. Even if it doesn't in a particular instance, you're still banking on implementation details of Qt remaining the same. Do you really wish to audit Qt code to ascertain whether it's a safe thing to do or not? No. Your code has a bug. Fix it. That's all.

Comment: Roger that. Could TableWidget.scrollToBottom() cause that much trouble? I understand to remove it from its current location, I just want to make sure that I and others like myself (new to Qt) fully comprehend what is going on.

Comment: @sudobangbang In most cases, if a `Qt` class is safe to use in a different thread, in the docs it will be stated, that `All functions in this class are reentrant` or something similar. For example in [`QImage`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QImage.html) docs it is stated, so it's safe to use that class in different threads. You should read about [threading basics in Qt](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/thread-basics.html), and [reentracy and thread-safety](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/threads-reentrancy.html).

Comment: To add to what thuga said, even if a class is reentrant it doesn't mean that instances of the class (objects) are reentrant. A reentrant class may be used to make objects in multiple threads but those objects may not necessarily be shared between threads.

Comment: @three_pineapples Yes, functions that are safe to access from multiple threads when dealing with shared data are marked as `Thread-safe`. For instance, all functions of [`QMutex`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmutex.html). This is explained [in the docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/threads-reentrancy.html#notes-on-qt-classes) pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

You should better design your code to avoid displaying this message. If you created the pixmap in another thread and "use" it in the GUI thread this might work now, tomorrow or forever ... or will not. Don't do that.

You cannot suppress the output of this warning without changing the Qt sources or installing a message handler.

Comment: I figured out what was generating the error, but right now I am sort of in a pickle. In order to make sure my TableWidget can dynamically handle data (update live), it has to constantly check for new data. So really I have no option but to link it to a thread. I will experiment with some various placements of the scrollToBottom() and report back.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much better if some of your actual code would have been available.

The reason you are seeing this is that you are using a different type of threading than QThreads . That is in general not advisable, but it is not illegal. There are three things that you will have to take care

1. All calls should end up being executed from calls within a QThreads object
2. All data passed through the signal-slots mechanism should be made such that there are no references/pointers to objects owned from a non-QThread.
3. Setup connections between object that receive call from non-QThreads to emit signal that are received with either `Qt::QueuedConnection` or `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection` connection type.